# Getting error with spell check in nano

Tags: nano, spell-checking

I am getting the following error while doing spell check in nano editor. Please help to resolve this.

```
Spell checking failed: Error invoking "spell": Bad file descriptot
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

edit nanorc file and enable spell checker.

```
sudo vi /etc/nanorc
```

and uncomment the line

```
set speller "aspell -x -c"
```

Comment: The guy wants to enable the spell check in nano so the suggested response instructs him to use vi to edit the nanorc file...:-)

Comment: You need both answers together!

Comment: @GrouchyGaijin That's true, you could always go with 'sudo nano /etc/nanorc'. 
Also if you wanted to find it faster you can use the ctrl+w shortcut and search for the word 'speller'.

Answer (score 8):

`nano` depends on a spell-checker program. Such a program is [aspell](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aspell)[image: Install aspell]. You can  install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install aspell
```

Comment: Still getting the same error after installing it.

Comment: You need both answers together!